# How to calculate the longest winning streak

Tags: sql

I have a table that records match results information in my PieCloudDB database.

| player_id | match_day | results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-17 | Win |
| 1 | 2023-10-18 | Win |
| 1 | 2023-10-20 | Draw |
| 1 | 2023-10-23 | Win |
| 1 | 2023-10-25 | Win |
| 1 | 2023-10-31 | Win |
| 2 | 2023-10-20 | Draw |
| 2 | 2023-10-22 | Lose |
| 2 | 2023-10-27 | Win |
| 3 | 2023-11-01 | Lose |

I want to calculate each player's longest winning streak. (not interrupted by a draw or lose)

For the above example data, the output should be:

| player_id | longest_streak |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |

My approach is:

```
select t1.player_id, max(t2.streak) as longest_streak 
from (select distinct player_id from Matches) t1
left join (
    select player_id, count(*) as streak
    from (
        select *, rank()over(partition by player_id order by match_day) as rk1,
        rank()over(partition by player_id, results order by match_day) as rk2
        from Matches) a
    where results = 'Win'
    group by player_id, rk1-rk2) t2
on t1.player_id = t2.player_id
group by 1
order by player_id;
```

But I get the outcome:

| player_id | longest_streak |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 |  |

I don't know what's wrong, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's kind of *gaps and islands* problem.

Sample data (match_day is just a number; didn't feel like typing all those dates):

```
SQL> select * from match order by player_id, match_day;

 PLAYER_ID  MATCH_DAY RESULTS
---------- ---------- -------
         1          1 win
         1          2 win
         1          3 draw
         1          4 win
         1          5 win
         1          6 win
         2          1 draw
         2          2 lose
         2          3 win
         3          1 lose

10 rows selected.
```

First identify groups; then, using conditional aggregation (why? To include players that didn't win at all; another option would be to use outer join with the original table) find number of wins in each group, and - finally - find the longest winning streak.

```
SQL> with groups as
  2    (select player_id, results,
  3       match_day - row_number() over (order by match_day) grp
  4     from match
  5    ),
  6  wins as
  7    (select player_id,
  8       sum(case when results = 'win' then 1 else 0 end) cnt
  9     from groups
 10     group by player_id, grp
 11    )
 12  select player_id, max(cnt) longest_win
 13  from wins
 14  group by player_id
 15  order by player_id;

 PLAYER_ID LONGEST_WIN
---------- -----------
         1           3
         2           1
         3           0

SQL>
```

Comment: Well, I tried your query but I get an error: `operator does not exist: date - bigint`, maybe `match_day - row_number() over (order by match_day)` needs to be modified.

Comment: Right; that's because I OVERsimplified it. MATCH_DAY column's datatype is *date* (or something like that) so - convert it to *number*. You didn't specify which database you use so I can't suggest function you'd use, but that might be something like combination of TO_CHAR( with appropriate format model, e.g. YYYYMMDD) and then applying TO_NUMBER to such a string.

Comment: I see, thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When `max(t2.streak)` is null, there will not be output. You can use `COALESCE(max(t2.streak), 0)` to avoid this situation.

Or you can try the following query adjusted from your approach in your PieCloudDB database.

```
with temp as
(
    select
    player_id,sum(case when results ='Win' then 1 else 0 end) streak
    from
    (
        select player_id,match_day,results,
        row_number() over (partition by player_id order by match_day) rk1,
        row_number() over (partition by player_id,results order by match_day) rk2
        from Matches
    )a
    group by player_id,rk1-rk2
)

select 
player_id,max(streak) longest_streak
from temp 
group by player_id
order by player_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is not less complicated. Indeed gaps-and-islands or sessionisation - in   my case with a counter at 1 when "results" changes, else 0, followed by a running sum of said counter, plus some "clever" logic of a sum of: 1 if "results" is 'Win' else 0. And finally get the maximum of that sum.

````
WITH
-- sessionise a) get counter when "results" changes
w_counter AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , CASE
      WHEN LAG(results) OVER(
        PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY match_day
      ) <> results
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS counter
  FROM indata
)
,
-- sessionise b) get running sum of counter from above
w_session AS (
  SELECT
    player_id
  , match_day
  , results
  , SUM(counter) OVER(
      PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY match_day
    ) AS session_id
  FROM w_counter
,
w_streak_length AS (
  SELECT
    player_id
  , SUM(CASE results WHEN 'Win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS streak_length
  FROM w_session
  GROUP BY
    player_id
  , session_id
)
SELECT
  player_id
, MAX(streak_length) AS longest_streak
FROM w_streak_length
GROUP BY
  player_id
;                                                                        ```
````